# Search Screen which accepts POST and GET

Tags: python, mongodb, web2py

Consider I'm a newbie in web2py.

I have this function in a controller to search entries from a company. The goal is search in database for three parameters from a form, but I want the function to accept parameters by GET as well:

```
@auth.requires_login()
def index():
    from datetime import datetime

    data['subtitle'] = 'My Screen'

    form = SQLFORM.factory(
        Field('company',
            type="reference company",
            label='Company',
            widget=SQLFORM.widgets.options.widget,
            requires=IS_IN_DB(mongodb, mongodb.company.id, '%(name)s')
        ),
        Field('initial_date', 
            label='Initial Date',
            type="date",
            requires=IS_NULL_OR(IS_DATE(format='%d/%m/%Y'))
        ),
        Field('final_date', 
            label='Final Date',
            type="date",
            requires=IS_NULL_OR(IS_DATE(format='%d/%m/%Y'))
        )
    )

    if str(request.env.request_method) == 'POST':
        print request.post_vars
        if form.accepts(request.post_vars, keepvalues = True):

            params = {}
            if form.vars.company is not None:
                params['company'] = form.vars.company
            if form.vars.initial_date is not None:
                params['initial_date'] = form.vars.initial_date
            if form.vars.final_date is not None:
                params['final_date'] = form.vars.final_date

            print 'Params: '
            print params

            redirect(URL('index', vars=params))

        else:
            for f in form.errors:
                print f + ': ' + form.errors[f]

        lista = {}
    else:
        query = None
        if request.get_vars.company is not None:
            query = mongodb.entry.company == request.get_vars.company
        if request.get_vars.initial_date is not None:
            query &= mongodb.entry.date >= datetime.strptime(request.get_vars.initial_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        if request.get_vars.final_date is not None:
            query &= mongodb.entry.date <= datetime.strptime(request.get_vars.final_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

        print 'Query: '
        print query
        if query is not None:
            list = mongodb(query).select()
        else:
            list = {}

    data['form'] = form
    data['list'] = list

    return dict(data=data)
```

Works perfectly only if I provide the company. If I search between dates, it show no results, even if the dates have matches in database.

Web2py lacks of good examples. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a POST form and then redirecting to the same action with a GET request, why not just submit the form via GET to begin with:

```
form = SQLFORM.factory(..., _method='get')
```

Regarding your query, `query &=` won't work when `query` starts off as `None`.

Comment: Nice solution. In fact I didn't know that is possible to define a form like this. Regarding the query object, the idea was just start it with some value to be used below. I'll test tomorrow morning and then I'll accept it.

Comment: With the SQL based adapters, `None &=` will generate an exception. With MongoDB, it doesn't generate an exception, but apparently the query does not end up working. So, just make sure `query` is not `None` when it gets to the first `&=`.